# jQuery animate mouseover/mouseout keep drop menu visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover, mouseout

I'm trying to make a basic drop down menu with animate and am running into the issue where I can't seem to figure out how to keep the dropdown part open until the mouse leaves. Is there an easy way to tell this to stay open? I know what I have is completely wrong regarding the .clickme mouseout function since it will unload the menu accordingly.

If anyone can help in this specific instance, I would be super grateful.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.clickme').mouseover(function() {
    $('#slidebox').animate({
        top: '+=160'
    }, 200, 'easeOutQuad');
});

$('.clickme').mouseout(function(){
    $('#slidebox').animate({
        top: '-=160'
    }, 200, 'easeOutQuad')
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going without any markup changes:

```
$('.clickme, #slidebox').hover(function() {
  $('#slidebox').stop().animate({ top: '30px' }, 200, 'easeOutQuad');
}, function() {
  $('#slidebox').stop().animate({ top: '-130px' }, 200, 'easeOutQuad');
});
```

Since your elements aren't parent/child related, easier to put absolute positions on the menu (it has `130px` in the CSS anyway), so no reason not to use the fact it has an absolute position.  Give it a shot, I tested against your site, seems to be the behavior I'd want in a menu.

Comment: +1 my solution was very close to yours, but it had an annoying bug... yours works indeed fine :)

Comment: Ideally, would I want to change this into a parent/child scenario in the long run?

Comment: @Ce - A child element would be different...but not necessarily *easier* in this case.  If later you had multiple slide downs, then yes, I would make them child elements.  Then, you could initially hide it and just give it a `slideToggle()` and the same easing effect.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into this as the main nav on the menu I am actually creating will have 2 slide downs in the end. Would I be dropping animate for slideToggle or combining the two? I'll do some research... :)

Comment: @Ce - You'd do something actually simpler, just position it at the bottom of the menu, 30px top or whatever with CSS, then something like this to animate: `$('.clickme').hover(function() { $(this).children('div').animate({height: 'toggle'}, 200, 'easeOutQuad'); });`

Comment: @Nick this kindof gives more of a blind effect of which I was trying to avoid. I like the actual slide down and everything comes with it style rather than it's there and just gets revealed. Or maybe I had implemented it wrong. Thanks for the insight though. I've dug myself deeper into this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out jquery hoverIntent

Comment: I've actually been reading about hoverIntent pretty much immediately after I posted this lol. Thanks!